# How to hide password in shell script duing ARM template deployment

Tags: shell, azure, passwords, azure-rm-template

I am using ARM template to deploy Azure VM.

template.json

```
    "adminPassword": {
        "type": "securestring"
    }
```

parameters.json

```
"adminPassword": {
    "value": null
}
```

When I use "null" in parameters, It will ask me enter password during deployment.

When I enter the adminPassword during deployment, it is showing as plaintext, But I want it to hidden (such as ******)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Using Azure CLI 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As 4c74356b41 said, currently, there is no way to do it directly.

You could use [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis) to avoid the password showing as  plain text.

Key Vault can store two types of information: Keys (Certificates) and Secrets. In your scenario, you need use Secrets. You need create a secrets in KeyVault.

```
##get password don't show plaintext     
read -s password
azure keyvault create --vault-name 'ContosoKeyVault' --resource-group 'ContosoResourceGroup' --location 'East Asia'

azure keyvault secret set --vault-name 'ContosoKeyVault' --secret-name 'SQLPassword' --value "$password"
```

After this you'll need to enable the Key Vault for template deployment.You can do this using the following commands:

```
azure keyvault set-policy --vault-name Contoso --enabled-for-template-deployment true
```

You need modify your parameter like below:

```
   "adminPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-guid>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault name>"
        },
        "secretName": "<seccret name>"
      }
    },
```

You could refer this template: [101-vm-secure-password](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-secure-password).

Comment: As an alternative, if you are using VSTS Release Management you can safely store passwords and settings in variables and use those at deployment time from the 'Azure Resource Group Deployment' steps. The advantage I see here is that you can reuse that variable instead of having to keep your KeyVault in sync with other places you use the same variable.