# Azure Key Vault Understanding

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault

The following github deployment allows me to deploy a simple Windows VM by retrieving the password that is stored in a Key Vault. Therefore the password is never put in plain text in the template parameter file.

Can someone explain what is meant with the statement:

> 'the password is never put in plain text in the template parameter
>   file?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use Key Vault, even `adminPassword` type is `securestring`, When you enter the adminPassword during deployment, it is showing as plaintext, not `******`. It is not safe. But if you use Key Vault, the password stores in Key Vault and encrypted save, other could not see your password.

In template, you should configure your template using Key Vault like below:

```
"adminPassword": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/vaultName"
    },
    "secretName": "secretName"
  }
},
```

Please refer to the similar [question:How to hide password in shell script duing ARM template deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534352/how-to-hide-password-in-shell-script-duing-arm-template-deployment).

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct. When I deploy a VM in Azure and add a password the password appears as ********

Comment: @Carltonp You deploy it on Portal? If yes, it appears as ****. But if you deploy template with PowerShell or CLI,  it does not appear as *****. In this scenario, for safe need, Azure recommends you use Key Vault to store password.

Comment: @Carltonp Use key vault, it could avoid your password appear as plain text. This will be safer. You could test two template, one uses key vault, one does not use, when you deploys with powershell, you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Carltonp `When I deploy a VM in Azure and add a password the password appears as ********` Do you mean your password link to a key vault or not? Sorry, I want to ensure this.

Comment: I mean when adding a password when creating a vm in the portal.

Comment: @Carltonp Yes, on Portal, the password appears as `********`. But if you deploy template using PowerShell or CLI, it appears as plain text not ciphertext. But if you store password in Key Vault, when you deploy template, you don't enter password. It also means `never put in plain text in the template parameter file`.

Comment: @Carltonp When you use parameter, you have two choices. 1. Store it in template file(for password,it  is not safe). 2. Enter when you deploy, but when you deploy it using powershell, the password appears as plain text(not safe).

Comment: When you use Key Vault, the password stores in Key Vault, you don't need store in template file or enter in plain text (more safer).